# Why can't TBB cast `int` to `const tbb::atomic<unsigned int>&`, but std::atomic can?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, tbb

I'm attempting to build a large project that has many dependencies. The last thing (?) preventing it from building is TBB's failure to handle casting of an `int` into an `const tbb::<unsigned int>&`. The annoying thing is that the same cast using `std::atomic` (specifically `const std::atomic<unsigned int>&`) works just fine. I can't refactor the code to use `std` instead of `tbb` (it uses other features of `tbb` that aren't part of `std`).

I've created the following simple test case:

```
#include <tbb/atomic.h>
#include <atomic>

void good(const std::atomic<unsigned int>& i) {
}

void bad(const tbb::atomic<unsigned int>& i) {
}

int main() {
    good(1);
    bad(1); // error C2664: 'void bad(const tbb::atomic<unsigned int> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const tbb::atomic<unsigned int> &'
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this (without removing use of TBB)? I need it to work in VS2017.

Edit:
Also, I get the following error:
`Error (active) E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "tbb::atomic<unsigned int>" Testmain.cpp    15`. So presumably, if there were a suitable c'tor, the cast would succeed. How can I add one? Is there an edit to `tbb/atomic.h` that would enable this cast?

Comment: what happens if you change the literal to `1u`?

Comment: passing `1u` produces the same error

Comment: `bad(tbb::make_atomic(1u));` fixes the error in this test. But I can't use that to fix the large project. I still need a way to make this cast work without using `make_atomic()`.

Comment: The [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506277) specifies that since C++11 a constexpr c'tor is available, so the two above code samples should be equivalent. I assume you are using TBB because you can't use C++11?

Comment: Looking at `tbb_config.h` I can see that `__TBB_ATOMIC_CTORS` is 0. It depends on `__TBB_CONSTEXPR_PRESENT`. The very recent VS2017 Update 15.3 adds `constexpr` support. I'm using a NuGet distro of TBB. Instead I need to build TBB myself so that I can enable `__TBB_ATOMIC_CTORS`. This sounds like problem solved.

Comment: [Why atomic<T> Has No Constructors](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506091) in official documentation

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! The problem was with the pre-processor defines being out of date for the NuGet distro of TBB I was using. VS2017 version 15.3.2 has support for `constexpr`, which is needed to enable `__TBB__ATOMIC_CTORS`. Thanks to @StoryTeller for pointing me in the right direction.

Fix: Git clone latest src of TBB and build. (Funny how shortcuts in C++ rarely are shortcuts).

Answer (score 1):

From the sources (which I found at https://github.com/01org/tbb/blob/tbb_2017/include/tbb/atomic.h, I don't have TBB myself) I can see that `struct atomic` only has an assignment operator defined, so no non-explicit constructor, which means that you have to explicitly construct it with `tbb::make_atomic`.

Comment: "But I can't use that to fix the large project. I still need a way to make this cast work without using make_atomic()"

Comment: Write your own class template which derives from tbb::atomic, e.g. name it axon::atomic, in which you implement a constructor for type T.  Then do a global string-change from tbb::atomic to axon::atomic.

Comment: Can't (too many code changes throughout the large project). Am looking through the `tbb_config.h` and see that there is a preprocessor `__TBB_ATOMIC_CTORS`, but I can't seem to turn it on... or it's already on and not the c'tors I need

Comment: Am using NuGet to get TBB. I see that `__TBB_CONSTEXPR_PRESENT` is set to 0, which is disabling `__TBB_ATOMIC_CTORS`, but should be 1 for VS2017v15.3... so NuGet distro of TBB needs to be rebuild/updated for latest version of VS2017